# ¿Cómo generar consultas en Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm

Tengo muchos problemas empezando con Laravel y uno de ellos son las consultas.

¿Cómo genero esta consulta en Laravel?

```
SELECT max(codigo_producto)
FROM producto
WHERE categoria_id = $id_cat
AND sub_categoria_id = $id_subcat
```

Comment: Por favor muéstranos primero que has intentado con la sintaxis de Laravel.

Comment: Como dice @Shaz sería mejor que pusieras lo que tú has intentado, y te recomiendo una vista a su documentacion oficial, https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Podrías generarlo de esta manera:

```
use DB;

$categoria = DB::table('producto')
                    ->select('codigo_producto', DB::raw('max(codigo_producto) as codigo_producto'))
                    ->where('categoria_id',$id_cat)
                    ->where('sub_categoria_id',$id_subcat)->first();
```

Espero te sirva de algo y ayude a solucionar tu problema.

Answer (score 2):

Si utilizas Eloquent sería algo como lo siguiente según la documentación:

```
$producto = Producto::where('categoria_id', '=', $id_cat)
            ->where('sub_categoria_id', '=', $id_subcat)
            ->whereRaw('codigo_producto = (select max(codigo_producto) from producto_table)')
            ->get([codigo_producto]);
```

En "producto_table" deberías poner el nombre real de la tabla perteneciente a Producto

Answer (score 0):

Tienes la funcion max():

```
$categoria = DB::table('producto')
             ->where('categoria_id',$id_cat)
             ->where('sub_categoria_id',$id_subcat)
             ->max('codigo_producto');
```